# JavaScript array.length = 0 changes memory reference?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angular controller I have:

```
  ...
    justNowSrv.queue.push(goal);
  }

  justNowSrv.start();

  $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
    justNowSrv.reset();
  });
```

And in my service I have:

```
var queue = [];

function setDefault() {
  queue.forEach(function(goal) {
    goal.justNow = false;
  });
  queue.length = 0;
}

function reset() {
  setDefault();
  $interval.cancel(justNowLoopCheck);
}
return {
  reset: reset,
  start: start,
  queue: queue
};
```

The `queue` array from `justNowSrv.queue` is referenced fine because I do `justNowSrv.queue.push(goal);` and I have no issues dealing with goal objects in the service.

When I leave the controller and go back, `queue.length = 0;` is ran. This breaks the memory mapping because pushing to the `queue` afterwards gives different behavior.

I always thought `array.length = 0` preserves the array memory reference. Is this not so?

I am able to fix the behavior if I use a object `var queue = { toRemove: [] };`, `justNowSrv.queue.toRemove.push(goal);`, and so on.

Comment: It changes nothing - in userland you are guaranteed to hold reference to the same JS object.

Comment: I guess this is specific to Angular then.

Comment: Take the google chrome debugger and compare the variable values (references) in every point of your interest. (the locally scoped variables can be exposed as global vars with right click on the identifier name in the "Scope" panel)

Comment: setting `queue.length = 0;` will not change the reference. I'm pretty sure I've done similar things in angular without problem. Maybe something else in the service is changing the reference? can you post the complete code?

Comment: I don't think so.... because `var queue = { toRemove: [] };` resolves the issue